# How can I delete old screen recordings made by MacOS QuickTime?

Tags: macos, quicktime, screen-recording

Most of the time, I only make screen recordings for temporary use, e.g. when filing a bug report. It often takes several tries to get the recording right. How can I delete the extra recordings that I don't need? Infuriatingly, there's no "Delete" nor "Open Movie Location" command in the QuickTime player.

I now know that I can change the default save location of recordings, but let's assume I didn't learn about that feature until I already had a lot of recordings already saved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't already changed the location, just right-click (control-click) on the name of the recording and you'll get a drop-down menu which will let you open the folder where the recordings are located.

Comment: I never would have guessed that the title bar of the window responded to right clicks! Thanks, this is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The default save location is `~/Library/ScreenRecordings/`. Open that folder in Finder by using SHIFT+CMD+G or the "Go...Go To Folder" menu.

Once you've opened that folder in Finder, you can move those extra files to the Trash while you're cursing the designers of this app for their omission of important cleanup and usability features.

Comment: Alternatively one can use Spotlight. This has advantage that you don't need to know the location of files. ⌘ + ␣ (to open Spotlight), enter "Screen Recording" (part of default file name of screen recording files) or custom filename you gave to screen recording, file with this name should be selected by default (if not, navigate to it with arrow key) and then ⌘ + R (reveal in Finder) which opens Finder window in folder where file is located. But I don't get this "important cleanup and usability features" complaint. What seems to be a problem?